# What are the modern names of the nations mentioned in Ystoria Mongalorum?

Tags: political-history, language, mongol-empire, political-geography, latin-language

Giovanni Carpini in his [Ystoria Mongalorum](https://archive.org/stream/textsversionsofj00hakluoft#page/68/mode/2up) lists as factions under the dominion of the Mongol Empire:

Nations that have been subjugated:

- Meniti
- Colona-Thorati
- Sassi
- Thoas
- Sarthi

It has been narrowed down to these 5 nations.

Comment: ...if it turns out to be something like "What would we call these in English today?", which ones do you know already? Getting all 46 is a lot of work, so I figure the least you can do is knock out the easy ones for us.

Comment: Translating these Latin ethnonyms to English and/or Identifying them with known factions/tribes.

Comment: Does anyone know how to make a list without double-spacing everything? I am not sure if my edit makes the question easier or harder to read.

Comment: And after you are done with this, please go through Ptolemy's Geographica and translate all the named tribes to their modern equivalents.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens maybe using `• Item<br>` works? I didn't try.

Comment: Do all of the factions mentioned,  exsist as nations in modern date?

Comment: @Rohit: No - if for no other reason than because modern nations tend to be much of larger area than typical *nations* of 700 years ago. Castile, Aragon, Leon and Granada were all distinct monarchies at that time, which now comprise the single nation of Spain. That doesn't mean that the geographical territories cannot be identified with reasonable precision.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens nation is people and culture, not geography much

Comment: @Rohit: Maybe according to sense (1a), but not according to sense (1c), of Merriam Webster: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nation.

Answer (score 7):

The list can be found in the original Latin on [page 68 of this edition of the Ystoria Mongolarum](https://archive.org/details/textsversionsofj00hakluoft), about 1/3 of the way down the page.

On Page 269 (through  295) are *C. Raymond Beazley's* **Notes on Hakluyt's Version of Vincent of Beauvis' Abridgement of Carpini**, discussing  the text.  On Page 278 at the top we have a discussion of *India magna* (noting that *India* in this context likely meant everything from Kabul to Saigon, our *Indies*): as that part of India between the Indus and Ganges rivers, so roughly corresponding to the modern country of India.

*Further India* would at his time have referred to the territories east of, or beyond, the Ganges, and so to our modern *Indo-China*, the countries of Burma, Siam, Laos, Malaysia, Cambodia and Vietnam.

*Lesser India*  would have been the territories west of the Indus River, or roughly modern Pakistan and Afghanistan.

Simply perusing the text I recognize the *Kytai* and *Naymani* as Mongol tribes (*nations*) subjugated by Temujin very early on. The *Merkiti* may also fall in this category.

- *Solangi* - Manchuria & Korea (p. 271)
- *Kara Kytai* - a Mongol tribe inhabiting Turkestan (perhaps a *greater* Turkestan) (p. 276)
- *Huyur* - the modern Uighurs (p. 277), a Turkish tribe inhabiting th area around Bishbalikh in the 13th century. (p. 277)
- *magna Bulgaria* - the region inhabited by the Volga Bulgars, around the Volga River south of Kazan. (p.285)
- *Hungaria magna* - the Bashkirs of Samara, Orenburg, Perm and Vyatka. (p. 285)
- *Kergis* - Circassians of the Caucasus (p. 286)

Note the (often vast) distance between the actual territory being referred to and what a simplistic translation might generate from modern country names. Also, at the time of Carpini's writing there was a mistaken belief in an Asian Abyssinia distinct from the (true) African Abyssinia. This likely is the source of the reference to Aethiopia, the modern country of which name was certainly never under any Mongol suzerainty.

**Update - two more**:

- Torci - possibly the Turks, rendered also *Turci* and elsewise (p. 261, Note 37)
- Yrchasi - [Circassians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circassians) (p. 262, note 40)

Comment: I l eave it to others to further flesh out OP's list.

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't think to scan through all the notes in the back.  http://i.imgur.com/WddZfMd.png  Is a page from a translation in English with an inconsistent list, nevertheless it narrows it down some.

Comment: Turks as in the Seljuk Turks of Rum? https://translate.google.com/#la/en/torci  Funny translation mentions Muscat which is a region in modern day Oman http://i.imgur.com/x8RyuQw.png

Comment: The notes reveal that the Yrchasi and the Kergis are both the Circassians.  The Kirgis has to be the actual Kirghiz http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yenisei_Kirghiz